# How do I set my Elastic Beanstalk application to use an Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to use websockets and SSL. Therefore I cannot use the default Elastic Beanstalk load balancer. I understand that Amazon has recently released an "Application Load Balancer" that supports websockets.

How do I configure my Elastic Beanstalk application to use this new type of load balancer?

Comment: I don't think that integration is yet available for application load balancer with elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Application Load Balancer can be used with Elastic Beanstalk now:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html

In order to used it your environment must meet the following requirements:
"must be in a default or custom VPC, and must have a service role with the standard set of permissions"

However when creating an environment via AWS console I haven't managed to find how to choose Application Load Balancer instead of a classic one. It has still the same option - "Load Balancer" to choose and when checked, it creates a classic Load Balancer. The only way I did managed to create an environment with Application Load Balancer is via aws eb cli as specified in the doc above:

```
$ eb create test-env --elb-type application
```

This will create Application Load Balancer. Then you will only need to configure it according your needs.

Comment: I needed additional parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826847/671393